# Best way to save Jenkins job-history/success-rate stats for 6+ months?

Tags: logging, jenkins, test-results

What would you all recommend as the best way to save Jenkins job-history/success-rate stats for 6+ months (for service-level agreement purposes)?  Normally, Jenkins jobs are configured to save history for a certain amount of time but on our Jenkins server, which has hundreds of jobs, it may not be realistic to have all jobs not clean up on a regular basis.

SO, I am wondering if there is a typical way people might store light-weight stats on job success history?

My only ideas are:

1. Run a CouchDB instance and do post-build curl statements to save
   stat information based on build variables?
2. Have jobs write a .txt
   file into the workspace and always append to it (but that gets
   deleted when workspace is cleaned).  Or a post-build .bash script step that writes to the file.
3. Other ideas???

Comment: I just saw today this plugin: https://github.com/jenkinsci/statistics-gatherer-plugin but I never actually tried it.  Plugin wiki page: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Statistics+Gatherer+Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send execution data to InfluxDB and visualize it using Grafana.

There is a plugin for that: [InfluxDB Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/InfluxDB+Plugin)

That plugin supports sending at least the following metrics:

- List item
- Build health
- Build number
- Build status message
- Build time
- Job duration
- Project name
- Tests failed
- Tests skipped
- Tests total

Comment: Looks like exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: There is another one for CouchDB which supports fewer parameters but is simpler to use: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/CouchDB+Statistics+Plugin